# My name is wrong on the NHS COVID Pass

Tags: covid-19, identification, names, nhs

They basically just cut out a piece of my first name.

I've only found [this reference](https://nhs-digital.zendesk.com/hc/en-gb/articles/4402645056657-My-name-is-incorrect-or-misspelt-How-do-I-change-this-in-the-NHS-App-) on how to correct it, but it refers to the NHS app, which I can't install on my phone unless I change the country of Google Play account, which I might not want to do.

Is there another way to have my name corrected on the COVID pass?

Comment: The cited reference states that the NHS uses the information held by the user's GP practice. In other words, the NHS app is used to _see_ the information (including your name) but not to _change_ that information. Have you approached your GP practice to make sure that the practice's record of your name is correct?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica i don't have the NHS app, so I don't know if my name is wrong in _that_ thing.

Comment: Because data is taken from your GP practice, the first step is to determine if you name is correctly recorded there.

Comment: The **only** way to get it changed is to contact your GP surgery to find out how your name is registered in their records. If it’s wrong (ie doesn’t match your passport) you’ll have to ask them to change it then wait until that change feeds into NHS covid pass data.